# Identifier is too long

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me to find why am getting identifier is too long error , even after having enough space for role in record.

**Exception :**

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 14, column 24:
PLS-00114: identifier 'ou=internal,ou=users,dc=chinas' too long
ORA-06550: line 18, column 24:
PLS-00114: identifier 'ou=internal,ou=users,dc=chinas' too long
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

**Code :**

```
declare
 type app_realm_rec is record
  (
    resource_filter varchar2(500),
    status varchar2(500),
    role varchar2(500)
 );
   type app_realm_tab is table of app_realm_rec index by pls_integer;
  realm_tab app_realm_tab;
  begin

  realm_tab(1).resource_filter := "/secure/records*";
  realm_tab(1).status := "true";
  realm_tab(1).role := "ou=internal,ou=users,dc=chinastreet,dc=com;ou=external,ou=users,dc=chinastreet,dc=com";

  realm_tab(2).resource_filter := "/secure/login";
  realm_tab(2).status := "false";
  realm_tab(2).role := "ou=internal,ou=users,dc=chinastreet,dc=com;ou=external,ou=users,dc=chinastreet,dc=com";
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello');
  end;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use single quotes for string in PL SQL

```
declare
 type app_realm_rec is record
  (
    resource_filter varchar2(500),
    status varchar2(500),
    role varchar2(500)
 );
   type app_realm_tab is table of app_realm_rec index by pls_integer;
  realm_tab app_realm_tab;
  begin

  realm_tab(1).resource_filter := '/secure/records*';
  realm_tab(1).status := 'true';
  realm_tab(1).role := 'ou=internal,ou=users,dc=chinastreet,dc=com;ou=external,ou=users,dc=chinastreet,dc=com';

  realm_tab(2).resource_filter := '/secure/login';
  realm_tab(2).status := 'false';
  realm_tab(2).role := 'ou=internal,ou=users,dc=chinastreet,dc=com;ou=external,ou=users,dc=chinastreet,dc=com';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello');
  end;
```